# Visual studio layout and toolbars are all changed

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I opened up Business Intelligence Design Studio (BIDS) the other day. Since then my visual studio toolbars and panes have been all screwed up. Commands are missing, panes never stay where I want them, etc.

Whenever I install VS, I usually select the Web Developer settings when the first time dialog comes up. I'm pretty happy with the layout it gives you with that. How can I set that again?

I'm using vs2008 sp1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS2008, go into **Tools > Import and Export Settings** and choose **Reset all settings**.  You will get the option of doing Web Developer settings the next time you start VS2008.